# Error uploading multiple images with Cloudinary

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, multer

When I try to upload multiple images with Cloudinary and Multer with NestJS I receive an error. I'm able to use the Cloudinary service in other components without issue.

Here is the error I'm getting at restaurant.service.ts:20:38:

> `Cannot read properties of undefined (Reading map`

Here is my code:

```js
async createRestaurant(CreateRestaurantInput: CreateRestaurantDto, user: UserDocument, restaurant?: Restaurant) {
  const { name, address, category, description, email, images, phoneNo } = CreateRestaurantInput

  // 1) Upload images to cloudinary
  const imagesPromise = images.map((image) => this.cloudinary.uploadFile(image))


  const imagesResult = await Promise.all(imagesPromise)

  const imagesLink = []
  const imagesIds = []

  // 3) Push images links & images IDs to the arrays
  imagesResult.forEach((image) => {
    imagesLink.push(image.secure_url)
    imagesIds.push(image.public_id)
  })

  const data = Object.assign({
    restaurant, 
    name, 
    address, 
    category, 
    description, 
    email, 
    phoneNo, 
    user: user._id, 
    images: imagesLink, 
    imagesId: imagesIds
  });

  return await this.restaurantModel.create(data)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it appears that `images` is `undefined`. Which means that `CreateRestaurantInput.images` is `undefined`. We cannot know why that is because the code that provides that value to this function doesn't exist in this post.

Comment: Also `Cannot read properties of undefined (Reading map` means that the part right _before_ `.map` is `undefined`. So this never even invokes `this.cloudinary.uploadFile` when this error is thrown.

Comment: i was found the problem in controller i was add fileinterceptor instead of filesInterceptor i was forget the s